# Unique Value in Rows to Column Header with Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

I have the following data:

```py
Name        Date        Class Attended
AB          15-02-2019       3
CD          15-02-2019       2 
AB          19-02-2019       4
CD          19-02-2019       2
AB          15-02-2019       1
CD          19-02-2019       3
```

I need output like:

```py
Name           15-02-2019   19-02-2019
AB              4 (3+1)     4
CD              2           5 (2+3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) and then [`pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects)

```py
df.groupby(['Name', 'Date']).sum().reset_index().pivot(index='Name', columns='Date', values='Class Attended').reset_index()
Out[12]: 
Date Name  15-02-2019  19-02-2019
0      AB           4           4
1      CD           2           5
```